# Bash; Replacing new line with ", " and ending with ".", can someone explain awk and sed, please?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

so let's say i have

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

and i need to replace all new lines by comma **and** space, and end with a dot like so

```
aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd.
```

I found this, but i can't understand it at all and i need to know what **every single character** does ;

```
... | awk '{ printf $0", " }' | sed 's/.\{2\}$/./'
```

Can someone make those two commands human-readable ?
tysm!

Comment: A solution to this task in plain `bash` would be: `content=$(<file); echo "${content//$'\n'/, }."`

Answer (score 4):

About the command:

```
... | awk '{ printf $0", " }' | sed 's/.\{2\}$/./'
```

Awk prints the line `$0` followed by `,`  without newlines. When this is done, you have `,`  trailing at the end.

Then the pipe to sed replaces the last `,`  with a single dot as this part `.\{2\}$` matches 2 times any character at the end of the string.

---

With sed using a single command, you can read all lines using `N` to pull the next line in the pattern space, and use a label to keep on replacing a newline as long as it is not the last line last line.

After that you can append a dot to the end.

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/, /g;s/$/./' file
```

Output

```
aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd.
```

Comment: OP didn't ask "how else can I do this task", they asked for help understanding their command.

Comment: @joanis Ah, you are right. Let me update that.

Comment: Nice `sed` command

Comment: Alternative sed solution: `sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;s/\n/, /g;s/$/./' file`

Comment: Or: `sed '$!s/$/,/; $s/$/./' file | xargs`

Comment: @potong Thank you, the `1h` part is to remove the leading newline that `H` causes right?

Comment: Correct. If `H` is used alone, then the final substitution would need to be extended to also remove the first two characters of the pattern space.

Answer (score 0):

ok,
first of all; thank u.

I do now understand that `printf $0", "` means 'print every line, and ", " at the end of each'

as for the sed command, a colleague explained it to me a minute ago;

in `'s/.\{2\}$/./'`,

`s/` replace

`.` any character

`{2}` x2, so two characters

`$` at end of the line

`/` by ( 's/ / /' = replace/ this / that /)

`.` the character '.'

`/` end

without forgetting to escape `{` and `}`, so u end up with
`'s/ . \{2\} $ / . /'`

but wait, it gets even better;

my colleague also told me that `\{2\}` wasn't necessary in this case ;
`.{2}` (without the escapes) could simply be replaced by

`..` 'any character' twice.

so `'s/..$/./'` wich is way more readable i think

'replace/ wich ever two last characters / this character/'

hope this helps if any other 42 student gets here

tism again

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ printf $0", " }'
```

This is awk command with single action, encased in `{`...`}`, this action is applied to every line of input.

[Printf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Basic-Printf.html) is print with format, here no formatting takes places but another feature of `printf` is leveraged - `printf` does not attach output row separator (default: newline) as opposed to `print`.

`$0` denotes whole current line (sans trailing newline).

`", "` is string literal for comma followed by space.

`$0", "` instructs awk to concatenate current line with comma and space.

Whole command thus might be read as: *for every line output current line followed by comma and space*

```
sed 's/.\{2\}$/./'
```

`s` is one of [commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/sed-commands-list.html), namely substitute, basic form is

```
s/regexp/replacement/
```

therefore

`.\{2\}$` is regular expression, `.` denotes any characters, `\{2\}` repeated 2 times, `$` denotes end of line, thus this one matches 2 last characters of each line, as text was already converted to single line, it will match 2 last characters of whole text.

`.` is replacement, literal dot character

Whole command thus might be read as: *for every line replace 2 last characters using dot*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the four lines are in a file...

```
#!/bin/sh

cat << EOF >> ed1
%s/$/,/g
$
s/,/./
wq
EOF

ed -s file < ed1
cat file | tr '\n' ' ' > f2
mv f2 file
rm -v ./ed1
```

Answer (score -3):

> ```
> echo 'aaa
> bbb
> ccc
> ddd' | 
>
> mawk NF+=RS FS='\412' RS= OFS='\40\454' ORS='\456\12'
> ```

```
aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd.
```

Comment: How is providing a different way to do the same thing that is even hard to understand an answer to the question "can you explain what this means?"?

Comment: @joanis : because OP's code uses both `sed` and `awk` rather inefficiently

Comment: OK, but then please take the time to explain your solution, I think OP will be just as lost here.

Comment: @joanis : nothing other than flattening the full input into a single row, and using `FS/OFS` to perform the typical functionality of `RS/ORS`

Comment: @joanis : I initially assumed he was using octals for the old reserved ASCII file seperator and record seperator control characters, but the numbers are different.